# Show values from database on canvas

Tags: c#, javascript, html5-canvas

I have a website which shows imes, personal records, results, limits, etc for Dutch swimmers.
On of the things i would like to add is a graph showing the progression of the swimmer over time for a certain stroke/distance.

For this i would like to use the HTML5 canvas.
I did some tutorials, read some sites and i am able to draw a nice graph via javascript.
But now : how to get both the database and (probably) javascript to work together ?
How do i get the values from my database to the javascript function, so it can draw the chart on my canvas ?....

Comment: you can try to load JSON content from you website, using a CGI in the middle

Comment: Why do you think the drawing process should be client-side?

Answer (score 0):

Put the database on the server. Add a script (php? Python? whatever your webserver has) to retrieve the values from the database via SQL and turn them into JSON (javascript object notation).

In your javascript, make an AJAX script to the server's data page described above, and voila, data in the browser.

The main problem is that javascript (particularly in a browser) is expected to come from, and communicate with, a server. It doesn't really have client-side database connection libraries.

If you want to do it all client-side, then I suggest you ignore canvas and html, and go with the c# option.